# Get metadata without deprecated StructDescriptor in Oracle

Tags: java, struct

If I use StructDescriptor I can get metadata like this:

```
final StructDescriptor structDescriptor = StructDescriptor.createDescriptor(typeName.toUpperCase(), connection);
final ResultSetMetaData metaData = structDescriptor.getMetaData();
```

Then I can use it to print column names and values in this columns, for example:

```
System.out.println(metaData.getColumnName(idx) + " = " + attribute);
```

Is there any way to do that same without deprecated StructDescriptor?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found only this way. It needs table name.

```
DatabaseMetaData meta = connection.getMetaData();
ResultSet rs = meta.getColumns(null, null, tableName, null);

while (rs.next()){
    System.out.println(rs.getString("COLUMN_NAME"));
}
```

This prints names of columns in the table.

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.ResultSetMetaData;

import oracle.jdbc.OracleDatabaseMetaData;
import oracle.jdbc.OracleTypeMetaData;

....

public static ResultSetMetaData getStructMetaData(Connection aConnection, String aSQLTypeName) throws SQLException {
    ResultSetMetaData lResult;
    OracleDatabaseMetaData lOraDbMetaData = (OracleDatabaseMetaData) aConnection.getMetaData();
    OracleTypeMetaData lTypeMetaData = lOraDbMetaData.getOracleTypeMetaData(aSQLTypeName);
    if (lTypeMetaData.getKind() == OracleTypeMetaData.Kind.STRUCT) {
        lResult = ((OracleTypeMetaData.Struct) lTypeMetaData).getMetaData();
    } else {
        throw new RuntimeException("\"" + aSQLTypeName + "\" is not struct");
    }
    return lResult;
}
```

Comment: Hi and welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour). Thanks for contributing but can you also add an explanation to your answer on how your code solves the issue?